# Why does loop revert back?

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting some data to MySQL table for testing purposes. The code below adds twenty rows for each `c`. And does so till the value of `c` is over a million.  After that, somewhere it starts adding rows for the ones added before. How can we solve this problem?

```
for($c=1; $c<=2000000; $c++)
{
    for($i=0; $i<=19; $i++)
    { 
        $query = "INSERT INTO selections (c_id, i_id) VALUES('$c', '$i')";
        mysql_query($query) or die("Cannot add... " . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want this? This should never be build.

Comment: This has got something to do with your field sizes. What are the limits for `c_id` and `i_id` in your table? `INT(X)`?

Comment: @Niels: I need to test a table that has int fields with numbers inside.

Comment: @Hanky Panky: fields are int(11)

Comment: Do you really wanna do 40 million inserts? Just wondering...
Can't believe something like that works on any common server configuration.

Comment: @Marcel Gwerder: yes, I need to test much more than 40 million.

Comment: Are c_id, i_id keys? Maybe setting them as `UNIQUE` will return an error that allows you to more precisely determine when ($c/$i values) does the problem occur.

Comment: What is the time out on the script? I suspect the execution of the script might be restarting after certain iterations.

Comment: @ Jay Bhatt: max_execution_time = 5600

Comment: @mustafa did you try setting time limit to 0?

Comment: You don't need to apply the third person singular twice in a sentence. Why does loop revert back, not reverts. The loop reverts back, why does it revert back.

Comment: Try adding a delay (sleep()) and printing the query after a million records to see whats causing the problem...

Comment: @Jay Bhatt: I tried adding 1 million first. Added it with no problem. Then set $c=1000001;$c<=2000000;$c++; and executed script but same problem occured again.

Comment: @mustafa Do you need to populate the table for testing purposes or inserting data itself is some sort of testing in your case?

Comment: @Peterm : This is real data used for an application

Answer (score 2):

If the purpose of your task is just to populate the data, and not trying to insert it with php script you can do that in mysql using a simple stored procedure like this

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_selections(IN max_value INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
WHILE i <= max_value DO
    INSERT INTO selections VALUES
     (i, 1), (i, 2), (i, 3), (i, 4), (i, 5), (i, 6), (i, 7), (i, 8), (i, 9), (i, 10), 
     (i, 11), (i, 12), (i, 13), (i, 14), (i, 15), (i, 16), (i, 17), (i, 18), (i, 19), (i, 20);
    SET i =  i + 1;
END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And execute it

```sql
CALL insert_selections(2000000);
```

*On my Mac it took several minutes*

Comment: +1 for this quick method. How can we use random numbers for twenty rows added. I do not want it as 1,2,3 so on.

Comment: Do you need random numbers in range 1-20 (that means that they can repeat) or you need exactly numbers from 1 to 20 but in random order?

Answer (score 1):

Php numbers unlikely wrap at millions level, so this is probably because of the field configuration of your database.. Simple test for php:

```
 for($i = 2000000; $i < 2000020; i++)echo "$i";
```

You will see that php can manage the numbers correctly...

**In mysql**

SMALLINT

```
A small integer
The signed range is –32768 to 32767. The unsigned range is 0 to 65535
```

MEDIUMINT

```
A medium-size integer
The signed range is –8388608 to 8388607. The unsigned range is 0 to 16777215
```

So if you use one of the above as **c_id**'s data type it will wrap after the upper limit of the range...

**Warning** Do not use mysql interface it is deprecated please use PDO or mysqli interfaces instead...

Comment: The fields I use are INT(11).

Answer (score 0):

The code shared, seems to work fine on my local, I added a combined `unique index` on the 2 columns

```
CREATE TABLE `selections` (
    `c_id` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `i_id` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX `c_id_i_id` (`c_id`, `i_id`)
)
```

I guess you have `2 instances` of the same page `executing`, causing duplicated values